# How do I set a variable to one of a set of types that implement a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I think the following code is self-explanatory.

```
extern crate crypto;

use crypto::sha2::Sha256;
use crypto::md5::Md5;
use crypto::digest::Digest;

fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args();

    let _       = args.next().expect("unknown argument environment...");
    let command = args.next().expect("no command given...");
    let data    = args.next().expect("no data given...");

    let mut digest: Digest = match command.as_ref() {
        "md5"    => Md5::new(),
        "sha256" => Sha256::new(),
        _        => panic!("algorithm not supported")
    };  

    digest.input_str(&data);

    print!("{} of \"{}\" is \"{}\"", command, data, digest.result_str());
}
```

As far as I understand, traits are used to tell the compiler that a specific set of methods are available for a specific type. In this case, the `input_str` and `result_str` methods are available for both `Sha256` and `Md5` since they are implementing the trait `Digest`. However, I can't figure out how to tell Rust that I want to continue with just using methods of the `Digest` trait.

Compiler output is:

```
src/main.rs:15:21: 15:31 error: mismatched types:
 expected `crypto::digest::Digest`,
    found `crypto::md5::Md5`
(expected trait crypto::digest::Digest,
    found struct `crypto::md5::Md5`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:15         "md5"    => Md5::new(),
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Idiomatic alternative to reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486227/idiomatic-alternative-to-reflection), also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403648/do-i-necessarily-need-to-box-here

Comment: Woops, I tried the search, but did not found those questions, thanks.